# Keychain popup freezes my safari when I visit specific sites

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, crash, keychain, performance

So I'm usually a chrome user, but ever since buying a macbook pro, I switched to safari because chrome drained my battery like mad and it generated too much heat. The transition wasn't bad, I actually like Safari....but the problem is that it freezes every time I visit reddit, Facebook, instagram, twitch, etc.

Whenever I visit the mentioned sites, Safari asks me if i want to allow it to store confidential info to keychain. The moment it pops up--without clicking on any of the options--the rainbow beachball cursor appears and I have to force quit the application. I've done this like a dozen times today. Is there any way to fix this? I'm using chrome to type this out and my macbook is already too warm for my lap.

Here's the console messages that generated after crashing safari by visiting Reddit and Instagram:
http://pastebin.com/pmS3BRe3

I cleared all the messages and performed these tasks in this order: Clear Display > go to Reddit (crashes) > force quit safari > open safari > visit instagram (crashes) > force quit safari.

BTW, I'm using the 2015 retina macbook pro model and using El Capitan. But this issue also existed in Yosemite.